# Class for command controller not put to autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a composer based TYPO3 7.6 installation and want to create an Extbase extension with a command controller.

The controller is registered in `ext_localconf.php` but the commmand controller isn't found because the class is not found in `typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Cli/CommandManager.php` in `public function getAvailableCommands()`

Namespace is also set: `namespace Foo\FooT3monitoringNotification\Command;`
The class is here `Classes/Command/NotificationCommandController.php`.

I've cleared all TYPO3 caches and did `composer dump-autoload`. Any idea, what I missed to do or what I can do to find out, why my class isn't put to autoload?

Comment: Have a look in the generated autoload_* in your composer directory - you should find your namespace there. Additionally: is it a composer based installation (I guess so ;)) or a "classic"?

Comment: Yes, it's cmposer based. And there is nothing about my class in any of the files in `vendor/composer/autoload_`.
What might prevent my class being added there? Do I need a `composer.json` in my extension?

Comment: Do you have an public actionCommand in the Controller? Something like ```public doMyTaskCommand()```?

Comment: Yes! For testing purposes I have `public function simpleCommand()` there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your newly created extension is not installed via composer, you need to define where to look for the classes. Therefore you need to add an autoload section to your root composer.json (that' means not in your extension, but in your TYPO3 distribution root folder):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Foo\\FooT3monitoringNotification\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/foo_t3monitoring_notification/Classes"
    }
}
```

More information: https://usetypo3.com/typo3-and-composer.html#c67